# Spring-boot yaml config change default path

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, config

I want to change *.yaml configs files default path to root level under "/config" directory (now default is "/src/main/resources").
Probably this is possible by create config bean but I never did it and in documentation cannot find information if this is possible to do in this way. I want to change default path so all config profiles should normally run using new location without any special additions except overwrite config. The same I want to do for configs using in tests but put into "/config-tests" directory.
Thank you very much for help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the location of config files by setting spring.config.location.

Ref - https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-location-of-application-properties-or-yml-file/#5_Customize_the_location_of_applicationproperties